# Jetpack Compose Canvas drawPath doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this composable that is supposed to allow drawing with the pointer to a canvas but when I move the pointer nothing happens

```
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@Composable
fun CanvasDraw() {
    val path = remember { Path() }

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInteropFilter {
            when (it.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    path.moveTo(it.x, it.y)
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    path.lineTo(it.x, it.y)
                }
                else -> false
            }
            true
        }) {
        drawPath(
            path = path,
            color = Color.Blue,
            style = Stroke(10f)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remember { Path() }` is caching lambda content value for next recompositions, but it cannot trigger recomposition when content on this object is changed. To make some state, which will trigger recomposition on changes in Compose, you need to use a mutable state of some kind - it's a new thing made for Compose.

You can find more info about state in Compose in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.

Storing points inside `Path` will not be clean, as it's not a basic type. Instead I'm using a mutable state list of points, like this:

```
val points = remember { mutableStateListOf<Offset>() }

Canvas(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectDragGestures { change, _ ->
            points.add(change.position)
        }
    }
) {
    drawPath(
        path = Path().apply {
            points.forEachIndexed { i, point ->
                if (i == 0) {
                    moveTo(point.x, point.y)
                } else {
                    lineTo(point.x, point.y)
                }
            }
        },
        color = Color.Blue,
        style = Stroke(10f)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code is supposed to draw seperate lines, [Phil Dukhov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3585796/phil-dukhov) said a solution for continuous line.

Blow code is to draw seperate lines. The drawback would be more loops with List<List<*offset*>>:

Image: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJKqn.png)

```
@Composable
// draws separate lines, but has more loops
fun CanvasDraw() {
    val pointsArray = remember { mutableStateListOf<List<Offset>>() }
    var temp = remember { mutableStateListOf<Offset>() }

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color = Color.LightGray)
        .pointerInteropFilter {
            val x = it.getX(it.findPointerIndex(0))
            val y = it.getY(it.findPointerIndex(0))
            when (it.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    // adding new referenced temp list of [x,y] points
                    pointsArray.add(temp)
                    // adding points for temp list
                    temp.add(Offset(x, y))
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> temp.add(Offset(x, y))
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> temp = mutableStateListOf()
                else -> false
            }
            true
        }
    ) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = Color.LightGray)
        ) {
            var counter = 0
            Log.d("TAG", "111   counter: ${counter}")
            pointsArray.forEach { list ->
                drawPath(
                    path = Path()
                        .apply {
                        list.forEachIndexed { index, offset ->
                            counter++
                            if (index == 0) {
                                moveTo(offset.x, offset.y)
                            } else {
                                lineTo(offset.x, offset.y)
                            }
                        }
                    } , color = Color.Blue, style = Stroke(10f)
                    )
            }
            Log.d("TAG", "222   counter: ${counter}")
        }
    }
}
```